# Does thrift IDL support generic types in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, rpc, thrift, idl

I want to remote process call a template C++ function using thrift, does thrift support this?

If it does, how can I write a thrift description file in this case?

Comment: Template functions are not callable.  They are just a way of stamping out code.  You will need to explicitly instantiate the templated function in C++ and then export it.

Comment: @RichardCritten, reasonable, but in writing a framework using thrift for rpc usage, I want to supply template functionality and deliver instantiation to users.

Comment: Template instantiation happens at compile time in C++. So it's hard to see how this would work.

Comment: Parametrized template methods cannot be "packed" in network protocol

Answer (score 0):

Templates in C++ are instantiated with types at compile time, so there is no way to allow user to provide `MyOwnType` during runtime. It would require some strange recompilation and reloading of parts of code during code execution...

So that's why it not usually supported to provide user with possibility to instantiate template on server side.

Further mode - Thrift was designed to support cross-platform communication. Imagine PHP client trying to instantiate some C++ template with class defined in PHP...

Also - please remember about security issues - passing any code to be executed on server side (template instantiation is in fact form of code execution) without verification is just a bad idea.

In Thrift you are able to use generic `vector` or `map` to define specific types, but functions need to be specific, not generic.

You could define as many functions as you might need with all types you want to support. You might consider even creating some script generating Thrift IDL from list of types you want to support.

Or you could use Thrift `union` type or `optional` fields to create "variant" type:

```
union Arg {
  1: optional Type1 t1; // not sure if union works well enough...
  2: optional Type2 t2;
}

void genericFun(1: Arg a);
```

IMHO: It that seems like you want to create "do everything" type of server, which is rarely a good idea - choose what your server really *has* to do and do it well.